# Git Code Editor Commit Error

Tags: git, shell

I have atom set up as my core.editor on git. However, when I try to either commit or tag I get an error referencing sublime, even when setting sublime as the main editor I get the same error.

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... subl -w: subl: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'subl -w'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

If I run git commit "Message", it does take the commit, but it won't open the editor. It does open when I run atom index.html

Thanks

Comment: What method are you using to set Atom as your editor? What's the output of `git config --get core.editor`?

Comment: I ran it and the output was `atom -- wait`, when configuring I used `git config --global core.editor "atom --wait"`

Comment: when running `echo $VISUAL $EDITOR` I get sublime